# get all the related detail of a a model object by using django ORM queries?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

These are  my django models.

***explaination of db models :***
*thinkpad* is a `equipment` of *laptop* `subcategory`.and *laptop subcategory* has a `category` called *electronics*.
now *laptop* can have many `attributes` like `processor,ram,color,screen_size`.

***Question :***
Find out all the `equipment` with their`equipment detail ,subcategory_name and attribute names,value`  which have *category_id =1* .

***Models :***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.category_id)+","+self.category_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "category"


class Subcategory(models.Model):
    subcategory_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="category_subc", verbose_name="category_id")
    subcategory_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.subcategory_id)+","+self.subcategory_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "subcategory"


class Equipment(models.Model):
    equipment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="subcategory_eq", verbose_name="subcategory_id")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.equipment_id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "equipment"


class Attribute(models.Model):
    attribute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(
        Subcategory, through="SubcategoryAttributeMap")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.attribute_id)+","+self.attribute_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "attribute"


class SubcategoryAttributeMap(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="subcategory_sub_attr_map", verbose_name="subcategory_id")
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attribute_sub_attr_map", verbose_name="attribute_id")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "subcategory_attribute_map"


class EquipmentDetail(models.Model):
    equipment_detail_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(
        Equipment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="equipment_eqdetail", verbose_name="equipment_id")
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="attribute_eqdetail", verbose_name="attribute_id")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.equipment_detail_id)+","+self.value

    class Meta:
        db_table = "equipment_detail"
```

***Desired Output:***

```
[ 
   { 
      'equipment_id':1,
      'subcategory__name':'laptop',
      'attribute_detail':[ 
         { 
            'attribute_name':'color',
            'attribute_value':'red'
         },
         { 
            'attribute_name':'ram',
            'attribute_value':'6gb'
         }
      ]
   },
   {   'equipment_id':2,
      'subcategory__name':'Mouse',
      'attribute_detail':[ 
         { 
            'attribute_name':'color',
            'attribute_value':'red'
         },
         { 
            'attribute_name':'dpi',
            'attribute_value':'800'
         }
      ]
    }

]
```

Comment: This (and a lot of other useful features FWIW) is [fully documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). May I kindly suggest you read this part of the doc ? This will save you a lot of time.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i have read this all still not able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this .

```
equipments = Equipment.objects.filter(subcategory__category__category_id=1)  


all_equipments_data = []  

# iterate over each equipment  

for equipment in equipments:
    single_equipment_data = {}  
    single_equipment_data['equipment_id'] = equipment.equipment_id
    single_equipment_data['subcategory__name'] = equipment.subcategory.subcategory_name  

    attributes_detail_of_equipment = []  

# iterate over each equipmentdetail of single equipment
    for eqdetail in equipment.equipment_eqdetail.all(): 

       attributes_detail_of_equipment.append({'attribute_name':eqdetail.attribute.attribute_name,'attribute_value':eqdetail.value})  

       single_equipment_data['attribute_detail'] = attributes_detail_of_equipment  

all_equipments_data.append(single_equipment_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
equipments= Equipment.objects.select_related('subcategory').filter(subcategory__category_id=1).prefetch_related(Prefetch('equipment_eqdetail', EquipmentDetail.objects.select_related('attribute')))
results = []
for equipment in equipments:
    temp = {
    'equipment_id': equipment.id,
    'subcategory__name': equipment.subcategory.name,
    }
    attributes = []
    for eq_detail in equipment.equipment_eqdetail.all():
        attributes.append({'attribute_name': eq_detail.attribute.attribute_name, 'attribute_value': eq_detail.value})

    temp['attribute_detail'] = attributes
    results.append(temp)
```

There will be 2 sql queries for this lookup and this will return data in your desired format.

Comment: this is also fetching all related equipments but i also need after getting queryset of equipments how to get output like this >  `equipments=[ [eq_id_1,subcategory_name,eq_attributes_name and respective value] [eq_id_2,subcategory_name,eq_attributes_name and respective value] [eq_id_3,subcategory_name,eq_attributes_name and respective value] ]`

Comment: and please explain your code and update your answer

Comment: so you want Subcategory objects as well? this query will get all equipments with all EquipmentDetail objects (with attribute objects related to a EquipmentDetail objects) related to a particular Equipment object.

Comment: i want all related detail of a equipment which is of category_id =1 , and  from your query lets say i am getting queryset but how to run loop on that to get list like i mentioned above. @NalinDobhal  .

Comment: @NaveenJain i have edited my answer, please check now.

Comment: i am upvoting your answer because that helped me to rethink approach you suggested. but it is not proper answer. if you can see every equipments can have many attributes. and according to your answer you are not handling this.

Comment: "laptop can have many attributes like processor,ram,color,screen_size". so do you want all the attribute of a Equipment as well?

Comment: yes you got right.please update your answer  @NalinDhobal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200312/discussion-between-naveen-jain-and-nalin-dobhal).